# pandas: Fill missing dates when keeping duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple `pandas` series:

```
import pandas as pd

quantities = [1, 14, 14, 11, 12, 13, 14]
timestamps = [pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 1), pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 1), pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 2), pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 3), pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 4), pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 5), pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 8)]
series = pd.Series(quantities, index=timestamps)
```

which looks as follows:

```
2015-04-01     1
2015-04-01    14
2015-04-02    14
2015-04-03    11
2015-04-04    12
2015-04-05    13
2015-04-08    14
dtype: int64
```

I would like to fill the missing dates i.e. `2015-04-06 = NaN` and `2015-04-07 = NaN` but keep the series as is, i.e.:

```
2015-04-01     1
2015-04-01    14
2015-04-02    14
2015-04-03    11
2015-04-04    12
2015-04-05    13
2015-04-06    NaN
2015-04-07    NaN
2015-04-08    14
dtype: int64
```

I've tried:

```
series = series.asfreq('D')
```

but get the following error: **ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis**. This error happens because of the duplicate timestamp values.

**Is there any way on Earth to achieve this?**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `reset_index()` should help you, besides from that, can't see a clear path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try:

```
s = pd.Series(np.nan, index=pd.date_range(series.index.min(), series.index.max(), freq='D'))
pd.concat([series,s[~s.index.isin(series.index)]]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
2015-04-01     1.0
2015-04-01    14.0
2015-04-02    14.0
2015-04-03    11.0
2015-04-04    12.0
2015-04-05    13.0
2015-04-06     NaN
2015-04-07     NaN
2015-04-08    14.0
dtype: float64
```

Timings:

```
%%timeit
temp = series[~series.index.duplicated(keep='first')].asfreq('D')
pd.concat([series, temp.loc[~temp.index.isin(series.index)]]).sort_index()
```

> 2.51 ms ± 52.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
series.name = "x"
calendar = pd.DataFrame(None, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start=series.index.min(), end=series.index.max(), freq='D'))
calendar.join(series)
```

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2:
>   FutureWarning: Creating a DatetimeIndex by passing range endpoints is
>   deprecated.  Use `pandas.date_range` instead.
>
> 2.07 ms ± 27.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
s = pd.Series(np.nan, index=pd.date_range(series.index.min(), series.index.max(), freq='D'))
pd.concat([series,s[~s.index.isin(series.index)]]).sort_index()
```

> 1.86 ms ± 15.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Thanks @root for this suggestion.

```
%%timeit
s = pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(series.index.min(), series.index.max(), freq='D')\
                      .difference(series.index))
pd.concat([series,s]).sort_index()
```

> 1.55 ms ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: my answer is the slowest but I learned something better here, great work!

Comment: @Terry Thank you.  This is why I love SO.  I learn something every day.

Comment: probably a little faster to setup your index as `index = pd.date_range(...).difference(series.index)` and then can avoid the `isin`/boolean indexing and directly `concat` the two.

Comment: @root  Great idea... let's try that.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks a lot for this very detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough, assuming you don't have millions of rows:

```
series.name = "x"
calendar = pd.DataFrame(None, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start=series.index.min(), end=series.index.max(), freq='D'))
calendar.join(series)
```

Output:

```
               x
2015-04-01   1.0
2015-04-01  14.0
2015-04-02  14.0
2015-04-03  11.0
2015-04-04  12.0
2015-04-05  13.0
2015-04-06   NaN
2015-04-07   NaN
2015-04-08  14.0
```

If you want a series you can access the column x of the resulting DataFrame: `calendar.join(series).x`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.concat`. Adding to your example code:

```py
series2 = pd.Series([pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan],
                    index=[pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 6), 
                           pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 7)])

pd.concat([series, series2], axis=0).sort_index()
```

returns

```py
2015-04-01     1.0
2015-04-01    14.0
2015-04-02    14.0
2015-04-03    11.0
2015-04-04    12.0
2015-04-05    13.0
2015-04-06     NaN
2015-04-07     NaN
2015-04-08    14.0
dtype: float64
```

That said, you are leaving yourself open to further difficulties by using a non-unique index. You would benefit from having a unique index level or non-index field to use for disambiguation.

Comment: You can just pass a scalar to `pd.Series` if you want the same value everywhere: `pd.Series(pd.np.nan, index=[pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 6), pd.Timestamp(2015, 4, 7)])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asfreq` removing the index duplicates and then concat where `temp.index` is **not in** original Serie

```
temp = series[~series.index.duplicated(keep='first')].asfreq('D')
pd.concat([series, temp.loc[~temp.index.isin(series.index)]]).sort_index()

output:
2015-04-01     1.0
2015-04-01    14.0
2015-04-02    14.0
2015-04-03    11.0
2015-04-04    12.0
2015-04-05    13.0
2015-04-06     NaN
2015-04-07     NaN
2015-04-08    14.0
dtype: float64
```